# NanoHTTPD server on desktop

Tags: android, desktop-application, httpserver, nanohttpd

I'm trying to serve a small file on my desktop using NanoHTTPD. The server starts fine but due to some unknown reason, it is unable to serve files. The same program works fine in Android. Can anyone give me some pointers? It's being more than an hour but I've got no clue. Here is my desktop version of NanoHTTPD server:

```
package com.desktopserver;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Map;

import com.desktopserver.NanoHTTPD.Response.Status;

public class MainClass {

    static int PORT = 8080;
    static WebServer MyServer;
    static FileInputStream fis;
    static BufferedInputStream bis;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyServer = new WebServer();
        try {
            MyServer.start();
            System.out.println("Webserver Started @ PORT:8080");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class WebServer extends NanoHTTPD {
        String MIME_TYPE;

        public WebServer() {
            super(PORT);
        }

        @Override
        public Response serve(String uri, Method method,
                Map<String, String> header, Map<String, String> parameters,
                Map<String, String> files) {
            try {
                File file=new File("/home/evinish/Music/Meant_to_live.mp3");
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                MIME_TYPE= URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
                System.out.println("\nMIME TYPE: "+MIME_TYPE);
                System.out.println("\nFILE NAME: "+file.getName());
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("File IO Exception");
            }
            return new NanoHTTPD.Response(Status.OK, MIME_TYPE, bis);
        }
    }

}
```

I do get this output, but that's it:

```
Webserver Started @ PORT:8080
```

What am I missing here? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: How did you test "it is unable to serve files"?

Comment: The URL is getting timed out. However, when I use the same NanoHTTPD code for android, I'm able to receive data. What are the other implications?

Comment: Ho do you connect to it in _both_ cases (Android, desktop)?

Comment: When the server is running on Android, I test it by accessing it via desktop. And when the server is running on desktop, it is not accessible even via localhost (on the same machine)

Comment: Did you try version from [project wiki](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/wiki/How-to-use-NanoHttpd)?

Comment: I found it here: https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't use "ServerRunner" class. ServerRunner hold you server to until any key press.

But in real application this don't work you want some change in NanoHTTPd file

line no 196 to

```
 myThread.setDaemon(false);
```